# Skewed class and Imbalanced class in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, data-science

Is there any difference between skewed class && imbalanced class in machine learning?Or both are same with different terminologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically , yes , they mean the same and are commonly used in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning skewed class mean the observation in dataset in the data set belong to one of two class has highest percentage than other. For example in caner classification problem, the people have cancer is 1%, so y = 1 and people who does not have cancer is 99% then y = 0. Their is imbalance between the class in the dataset. 
So skewed class and imbalanced class one and the same.